# How to load testing an application that calling external service APIs using Jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, external, load-testing

I currently want to perform a load testing an application using Jmeter but some functions need to call an external service APIs.

So I want to know how do I test those APIs without the app calling the actual external API service.

For example, I want to test an application that calling Google Maps Platform [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions?hl=en) to get a direction from point A to B.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of [Mock Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), you can configure your application to point to your own external API implementation instead of Directions API which will return static or random or pre-defined response.

One of possible options is using i.e. [Wiremock](https://wiremock.org/) for this, you can interact with [Wiremock REST API](https://wiremock.org/docs/api/) using [JMeter's HTTP Request samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing) to create/amend mock responses on the fly.